# Is there a way to easily get the logarithm of a np.ndarray containing errors

Tags: numpy, logarithm

If I have a `np.array` of values, `Y`, with a `no.array` of corresponding errors, `Err`, the error in the log scale will be

```
Err_{log} =  log(Y+Err) - log(Y) = log ((Y+Err)/Y)
```

While I can place this in my code, this isn't much readable. Is there a function that does that?

Comment: It seems to me that calculating `Err_log = np.log(Err/Y + 1)` doesn't get much more readable than that.

Comment: You could also use `np.log1p`, e.g. `Err_log = np.log1p(Err/Y)`

Comment: @Warren I didn't see that one coming, great! That function has interesting properties.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I knew that there is more elegant way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You can post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy has the function [`log1p(x)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html) that computes the log of 1+x. So you could write:

```
Err_log = np.log1p(Err/Y)
```